# How to have full citation in both references and footnote?

Tags: biblatex, citing, footnotes

I want my citations to both appear in the reference page, and in the footnotes of each page as a full citation. I can do `\footfullcite` after each citation manually to achieve the result, but then I have 60 citations to type in. is there a more convenient way to achieve what I want?

I have tried doing the verbose style and lipsum trick. However the resulting reference page is not in the ieee style that I want.

Thanks very much for your time. Just started using latex and finding it extremely helpful. and confusing at the same time

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,sorting=none,citestyle=ieee]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
\begin{document}

free text free text free tex \cite{ref1}. free text free text \cite{ref3} \cite{ref4}.

\pagebreak
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Redefine the guts of `\cite` to do both what `\cite` used to do and `\footfullcite`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,sorting=none,citestyle=ieee]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\let\oldblx@cite@cite\blx@cite@cite
\def\blx@cite@cite#1#2#3#4{%
   \oldblx@cite@cite{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}%
   \blx@cite@footfullcite{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}%
}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{ref.bib}
\begin{document}

free text free text free tex \cite{ref1}. free text free text \cite{ref3} \cite{ref4}.

\pagebreak
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: This completely wrecks `biblatex`'s pre- and post-note handling and is in general not recommended for `biblatex`. Multiple citations are normally also not handled rather well using this approach.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I'll see if I can fix those problems. Perhaps `\patchcmd` does better?

Comment: I believe you'd have to go with `\DeclareCiteCommand`. But still, letting `\cite` be `\footfullcite` in IEEE, seems akward, to say the least.

Comment: My usual solution is to use `\DeclareCiteCommand` as gusbrs suggests. I'm not entirely sure if you can use `\patchcmd` to do this, but the interface provided for this by `biblatex` is definitely `\DeclareCiteCommand`. With `\DeclareCiteCommand` one needs to use commands that are not as high-level as `\cite` and `\footfullcite`.

Comment: I think I fixed it.

Comment: The difficulty that comes up in using `\DeclareCiteCommand` is that the main citation is only generated once and then put into a wrapper. So it's not clear how to merge `\footfullcite` which uses `\mkbibfootnote` as a wrapper with the normal `\cite` command, which uses no wrapper.

Comment: The solution is to just merge the internal commands that `\DeclareCiteCommand` makes, so that the whole process is done once using the `\cite` code and once with the `\footfullcite` code.

Comment: I still prefer `\DeclareCiteCommand`, but +1 for digging into the internals. It might indeed be a bit more difficult to get `\DeclareCiteCommand` going for this particular case than I thought.